# How to extract path of each element from SVG?

Tags: android, svg

I need to get path of each element from SVG and put them into ArrayList. There are lot of ways to create Drawable. But I need only path of each element on SVG.

Eg: `<path d="M31,3h38l28,28v38l-28,28h-38l-28-28v-38z" fill="#a23"/>`

How to do this?

Comment: just use an xml parser

Comment: @pskink can you please give me some relevance?

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve? what has SVG to do with `android.graphics.drawable.Drawable`?

Comment: Actually I want to get all elements in SVG separately.

Comment: so as i said parse your SVG with an xml parser

Answer (score 1):

This stack overflow question may help  you to get some understanding of svg path data reading  [easiest-way-to-read-in-svg-path-data-with-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973777/easiest-way-to-read-in-svg-path-data-with-java)